# Diagonalization of quadratic form: asymmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I have a quadratic form, say: $A^2+B^2+4AB$.

If I write it in matrix form $V^TQV$ where symmetric $Q=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 2 \\
   2 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ everything goes fine with diagonalization.

Conversely, if I try to write it as $V^TQ'V$ where non-symmetric $Q'=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 3 \\
   1 & 1 \\
 \end{array} } \right]$, I get different eigenvectors that DO NOT diagonalize the form: i.e. when expressing $A$ and $B$ as function of $A'$ and $B'$, the off-diagonal terms do not go away.

What I am asking is the following: since the expression $V^TQ'V$ seems to work perfectly fine in reproducing the form, why I cannot use it for diagonalization?

What is the profound cause of the fact that I need to use a symmetric matrix for diagonalizing a quadratic form?

which are the feature of symmetric matrices that allow diagonalization of quadratic forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason to prefer a symmetric matrix over an asymmetric matrix is that the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are real. This is no longer the case for asymmetric matrices.

---

Symmetric matrices are characterized by the fact that not only are their eigenvalues all real, but they can be written as $S=ODO^T$ where $O$ is orthogonal (with real entries) and $D$ is a diagonal matrix of real eigenvalues. Having such a representation is equivalent to being a symmetric matrix.

Comment: In my example also the eigenevalues of $Q'$ are real, though. There should be more than this, I suspect.

Comment: Your question is subjective. It appears what you are trying to ask is for a set of properties that characterize symmetric matrices in a way that is more natural in the context of quadratic forms. Is this correct? (In general, as this is a math site and not a philosophy site, it is better to ask precise mathematical questions.)

Comment: Correct, thank you!. Rephrasing in a more precise way: which are the feature of symmetric matrices that allow diagonalization of quadratic forms? (also editing the main question)